# React component not rendering despite event firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm making a blog with react, next.js, and json-server. I have come as far as dynamically loading blog posts and other UI, but now when I'm trying to load the comments dynamically as well, it's not working.

The component in question is this one.

```
const Comments = ({ id }) => {
  const [com, setCom] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getComments = async () => {
      const comment = await fetchPost(id);

      if (comment["comments"].length == 0) return;

      const comments = [...comment["comments"]];

      setCom([...comment["comments"]]);
    };

    getComments();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {com.map((p) => {
        console.log(p.comment);
        <Comment key={p.id} comment={p.comment} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I know that the component is getting called and have the information as I'm logging it to console inside map. What I can't get my head around is why it is not rendering as it is a near carbon copy of how I render the blog-posts.

Aside from the above, I have tried the following:

- checked syntax
- Running `<Comment/>` with and without a key
- putting in strings directly inside the component com.map, instead of p.comment == does not render
- lifting state and useEffect up to `<Post/>`

Comment: There's probably no need to `spread` the data out like that. You could probably do       `setCom(comment.comments);`

Comment: Even though in this case you are probably right, I don't think it is a good idea to recommend a beginner to avoid immutability in a framework such as React.

Comment: But there's no state _update_, there's just an immediate state _change_. I agree that immutability is an important concept, but using `spread` here doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is not returning anything so React has nothing to render

```
{com.map((p) => (
  <Comment key={p.id} comment={p.comment} />;
))}
```

---

The following code returns nothing

```js
() => { const value = 1; }
```

The following code returns `1`

```js
() => { const value = 1; return value;}
```

The following code returns `1`

```js
() => 1
```

Comment: That was the difference between the working one and the none working one. thx! I shall get a better font in my editor. :P